# excel to return result on index-small-if with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, excel-2010

---

Dear Community,

I am currently stuck with a dilemma.
I have built a tracking sheet for development work with our team that allowed us to manage and track tasks required for the completion of a requirement and software releases.

For each release i had tables that would populate a table containing relevation information for the different team members from a source sheet helping us with the tracking of our tasks and contained further automation for a burndown chart.
I only consider myself a padawan regarding excel and largely built this sheet based on some google fu and trial & error. Now let us get to the details

Table Content

- Request ID
- Requirement ID
- Effort
- Release
- etc.

Used Statement:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($J$1:$M$4;SMALL(IF($J$1:$J$4=$B$7;ROW($J$1:$M$4));ROW(1:1));4));"";INDEX($J$1:$M$4;SMALL(IF($J$1:$J$4=$B$7;ROW($J$1:$M$4));ROW(1:1));1))
```

Unfortunately I do not know how I should go ahead from here.
I expect to modify the statement so the return corresponds to a result satisfying both or more criteria i.e. only Release 2.0 and Requirement ID DFE1.

I have attempted nesting an IF statement as seen below but with no success.

```
=INDEX($J$1:$M$4;SMALL(IF($J$1:$J$4=$B$7;ROW($J$1:$M$4);IF($K$1:$K$4=$B$8;ROW($J$1:$M$4)));ROW(1:1));1)
```

Kindly suggest possible ways to go about this.

If you require any further details please do let me know.

Comment: give some screen shot of what your sheet is like, or give us the references to columns, and cells you use in your formula. And give us the expected result you want, do this in a screen shot plz.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Excel 2010` then you can use `IFERROR` rather than `ISERROR` to avoid repetition in the formula, so your original formula can be

`=IFERROR(INDEX($J$1:$M$4;SMALL(IF($J$1:$J$4=$B$7;ROW($J$1:$M$4));ROW(1:1));1);"")`

Then if you want to add additional conditions to that you can use * as a "pseudo AND" so for your two conditions that would be

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$1:$M$4;SMALL(IF(($J$1:$J$4=$B$7)*($K$1:$K$4=$B$8);ROW($J$1:$M$4));ROW(1:1));1);"")
```

More conditions can be added in the same way if required

That should work OK but for added "robustness" I would suggest this version where the first formula is in cell D2 (adjust as required).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$1:$M$4;SMALL(IF(($J$1:$J$4=$B$7)*($K$1:$K$4=$B$8);ROW($J$1:$M$4)-MIN(ROW($J$1:$M$4))+1);ROWS(D$2:D2));1);"")
```